# Is there any way to use Inject directly from model or other class without controller?

Tags: scala, playframework, dependency-injection, guice

I just start using playframework 2.5 scala.

The example about usage of Inject I found is only from controller.Like:

```
class SampController @Inject()(service:Service) extends Controller{
  def index = Action{implict request =>
    ..
    sample.exec(service)
    ..
  }
}

class Sample{
  def exec(service:Service) = {
    ...
  }
}
```

But, I'd like to injected object directly from "Sample".
Is there any way?

```
class SampController extends Controller{
  def index = Action{implict request =>
    ...
    sample.exec()
    ...
  }
}

class Sample{
  def exec = {
     val service:Service = #Any way to get injected object here?
     ...
  }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why? You can use constructor parameters for such case?

Comment: @cchantep You mean class Sample @Inject()(service:Service){... and bind this to Guice?

If so, then I have to change controller to class SampController @Inject()(sample:Sample)...

It is not good for me.
I'd like to avoid fat controller.

Comment: Well injecting `Service` into `Sample` and `Sample` into `SampController` is perfectly fine. This doesn't make your controller "fat". It's just how dependency injection in play with guice works.

Comment: @Roman Thank you!
I'm not got used to DI, and feel some strangeness to this. But if it is common sense of play&guice, I obey to it.

Comment: If the service is only used by `exec` it could also be passed as a parameter: `def exec(service: Service)` no need for guice magic for `Sample`. And for the controller `SampleController @Inject() (service: Service)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use guice dependency injection on `Sample` and inject `Service` into it, then inject `Sample` into controller.

```
@Singleton
class SampController @Inject() (sample: Sample) extends Controller {
  def index = Action { implict request =>
    ...
    sample.exec()
    ...
  }
}

@Singleton
class Sample @Inject() (service: Service) {
   def exec = {
    service.doSomething()
    ...
  }
}
```